# how to get system unique id using vc++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, system, unique

I'm new to vc++ language so I want to get system unique id using vc++ language. so please can anybody help me in coding how to get system unique id?

Comment: What makes you think systems have a unique id?

Comment: What is a "system unique id" exactly? An id that is guaranteed to be unique within the scope of the system the process is currently running on, or an id that uniquely identifies the current system?

Comment: I think you need to give us a little more context. Can you let us know how this unique ID will be used in your application? This will allow us to decide what solution may or may not be adequate.

Comment: System has a unique Id, wmi query can be used in windows.

Answer (score 2):

You want to look at `CoCreateGuid` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms688568(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: How does that identify the system?

Comment: There is no function that could generate same id later. So this function doesn't identify system in any way.

Comment: To answer the 3 comments above, you generate then store the GUID and use it to identify your machine on a wider system like a network or whatever the context is. No different to getting the MAC address from a network card only this doesn't require your system has a network card. +1 for being less constrained than using a MAC address.

Comment: this doesnt answer the question, There is no guaranty that the unique ID will be same.

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the MAC address from the network card. This should be unique but will change if your change the network card.

See the api GetAdaptersInfo.
reference
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917(VS.85).aspx

Comment: At least three reasons - it may not have a network card, it may have more than one network card, the network card(s) may be changed.

Comment: If more than one network card, choose the first. If network card changes , have a re-registration process. If no network card, give the machine to a museum and buy a new one. ;.)

I agree MAC address isn't a 100% solution, but it should cater for the vast majority of situations.

Comment: In retrospect generating a GUID rather than using MAC address is probably better. You then don't need a network card to be installed. Having said that , what system would need a unique identifier unless it was networked in the first place? .. hmmmmm....we definitely need more context from the question.

Comment: Not only can you switch network cards, you can spoof the MAC address as well, there are simple free programs all over that can do it. Hell, even linksys routers have a menu option to spoof the routers mac address.

Comment: @kelton52, of course you can. We have no context as to wether the unique identifier was to be used in a trusted environment or not. In an untrusted environment mac address wouldn't be appropriate.

Comment: The only environment that is trusted with this is this person, using this program, on his/her computer. And that's it. As soon as you at least remove this person, it's no longer trusted.

Answer (score 1):

IF you're looking to create a unique ID based on a specific machine, one of the ways I can think of is using good old boost.

For instance, you can look up one of the boost candidate libraries called UUID (GUID generation) and you could look up boost::filesystem. Using the filesystem you could get creation dates on some of the system files, and use those strings to generate a GUID.

Just a thought, hope it helps

- you can find the UUID library
  [here](http://www.boostpro.com/vault/)

  - you can find the Filesystem library
    documentation [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm)

Comment: That identifies the date of the Windows installation. If I have to reinstall, or touch the files somehow, I get a new id.

Answer (score 0):

One value that I've seen used is the hard disk volume ID of the C-drive.  It will change when you swap the drive though.

Answer (score 0):

As I think the answers so far and the responses to them indicate, the real answer is not to write code that requires a unique system ID. This is very easy to do, in fact (as there is no such ID) it is the only sensible way to write applications. Anything that depends on drive serial number, MAC addresses etc. will inevitably break when the system is changed or upgraded.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via WMI query to "Win32_ComputerSystemProduct" class.

```
HRESULT hres;

// Step 1: --------------------------------------------------
// Initialize COM. ------------------------------------------

hres = CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
if (FAILED(hres)) { return 1; }

// Step 2: --------------------------------------------------
// Set general COM security levels --------------------------

hres = CoInitializeSecurity(nullptr, -1, nullptr, nullptr, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE,
    nullptr, EOAC_NONE, nullptr);
if (FAILED(hres)) { return 1; }

// Step 3: ---------------------------------------------------
// Obtain the initial locator to WMI -------------------------
IWbemLocator *pLoc = nullptr;
hres = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_WbemLocator, nullptr, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IWbemLocator, reinterpret_cast<LPVOID *>(&pLoc));
if (FAILED(hres)) { return 1; }

// Step 4: -----------------------------------------------------
// Connect to WMI through the IWbemLocator::ConnectServer method

IWbemServices *pSvc = nullptr;

// Connect to the root\cimv2 namespace with
// the current user and obtain pointer pSvc
// to make IWbemServices calls.
hres = pLoc->ConnectServer(_bstr_t(L"ROOT\\CIMV2"), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr, NULL, nullptr, nullptr, &pSvc);

if (FAILED(hres)) { pLoc->Release();        CoUninitialize();        return 1; }


// Step 5: --------------------------------------------------
// Set security levels on the proxy -------------------------

hres = CoSetProxyBlanket(pSvc, RPC_C_AUTHN_WINNT, RPC_C_AUTHZ_NONE, nullptr,
    RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_CALL, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, nullptr, EOAC_NONE);

if (FAILED(hres)) { pSvc->Release();        pLoc->Release();        CoUninitialize();        return 1; }

// Step 6: --------------------------------------------------
// Use the IWbemServices pointer to make requests of WMI ----

// For example, get the name of the operating system
IEnumWbemClassObject* pEnumerator = nullptr;
hres = pSvc->ExecQuery(
    bstr_t("WQL"),
    bstr_t("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystemProduct"),
    WBEM_FLAG_FORWARD_ONLY | WBEM_FLAG_RETURN_IMMEDIATELY,
    nullptr,
    &pEnumerator);

if (FAILED(hres)) { pSvc->Release(); pLoc->Release(); CoUninitialize(); return 1; }

// Step 7: -------------------------------------------------
// Get the data from the query in step 6 -------------------

IWbemClassObject *pclsObj = nullptr;
ULONG uReturn = 0;

HRESULT hr = pEnumerator->Next(WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &pclsObj, &uReturn);
VARIANT vtProp;

// Get the value of the Name property
hr = pclsObj->Get(L"UUID", 0, &vtProp, 0, 0);
wcout << " OS Name : " << vtProp.bstrVal << endl;
VariantClear(&vtProp);

pclsObj->Release();

// Cleanup
// ========

pSvc->Release();
pLoc->Release();
pEnumerator->Release();
CoUninitialize();

return 0;
```